# How can my services communicate with each other in a kubernetes deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

Part of my deployment looks like this

```
client -- main service  __ service 1
                       |__ service 2
```

**NOTE:** Each of these 4 services is a container and I'm trying to do this where each is in it's own Pod (without using multi container pod)

Where main service must make a call to service 1, get results then send those results to service 2, get that result and send it back to the web client

main service operates in this order

- receive request from web client pot :80
- make request to http://localhost:8000 (service 1)
- make request to http://localhost:8001 (service 2)
- merge results
- respond to web client with result

My deployments for service 1 and 2 look like this

SERVICE 1

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Service 
metadata: 
  name: serviceone 
spec: 
  selector: 
    run: serviceone 
  ports: 
    - port: 80 
      targetPort: 5050 

--- 

apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment 
metadata: 
  name: serviceone-deployment 
spec: 
  replicas: 1 
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      run: serviceone 
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        run: serviceone 
    spec: 
      containers: 
      - name: serviceone 
        image: test.azurecr.io/serviceone:v1 
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent 
        ports: 
        - containerPort: 5050
```

SERVICE 2

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Service 
metadata: 
  name: servicetwo
spec: 
  selector: 
    run: servicetwo 
  ports: 
    - port: 80 
      targetPort: 5000 

--- 

apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment 
metadata: 
  name: servicetwo-deployment 
spec: 
  replicas: 1 
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      run: servicetwo 
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        run: servicetwo 
    spec: 
      containers: 
      - name: servicetwo 
        image: test.azurecr.io/servicetwo:v1 
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent 
        ports: 
        - containerPort: 5000
```

But I don't know what the service and deployment would look like for the main service that has to make request to two other services.

**EDIT:** This is my attempt at the service/deployment for main service

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Service 
metadata: 
  name: mainservice
spec: 
  selector: 
    run: mainservice 
  ports: 
    - port: 80 # incoming traffic from web client pod
      targetPort: 80 # traffic goes to container port 80
  selector: 
    run: serviceone 
  ports: 
    - port: ?
      targetPort: 8000 # the port the container is hardcoded to send traffic to service one
  selector: 
    run: servicetwo 
  ports: 
    - port: ? 
      targetPort: 8001  # the port the container is hardcoded to send traffic to service two  

--- 

apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment 
metadata: 
  name: mainservice-deployment 
spec: 
  replicas: 1 
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      run: mainservice 
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        run: mainservice 
    spec: 
      containers: 
      - name: mainservice 
        image: test.azurecr.io/mainservice:v1 
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent 
        ports: 
        - containerPort: 80
```

**EDIT 2:** alternate attempt at the service after finding this https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#multi-port-services

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Service 
metadata: 
  name: mainservice
spec: 
  selector: 
    run: mainservice 
  ports: 
    - name: incoming
      port: 80 # incoming traffic from web client pod
      targetPort: 80 # traffic goes to container port 80
    - name: s1
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8000 # the port the container is hardcoded to send traffic to service one
    - name: s2
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8001  # the port the container is hardcoded to send traffic to service two
```

Comment: Is your main app (`main service`) running in the kubernetes cluster too?

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma yes, all 4 items are in the cluster (web client, main service, and service 1 and 2)

Comment: You can not add `.spec.selector` and `.spec.ports` more than once and you do not have to add extra selector and ports. You will just add the selector and the ports for its own workloads not for others. That is why only keep selector `run: mainservice` and  ports for mainservice in the Service object named `mainservice`. You are thinking that if you do not add the selector and the ports of service1 and service2 then how the mainservice will make a request to them?

Comment: Then why first time you did not specify that you want to deploy all of them as different Pods and your mainservice code uses the other two services as localhost in the code?

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma So you can direct traffic from Port 80 of Pod  to container targetPort 5000, similarly I thought that you could make a request inside the Pod (localhost:8000) and somehow specify which port on the Pod it gets directed to, and then through label select which external Pod to send the traffic.

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma that is the recommended default configuration for services (one container per pod) , I thought everyone assumed this to be true except for special cases like sidacars, loggers etc sorry for any confusion

Comment: So you can do everything you want to do if you edit your mainservice code, like @BurakSerder said before. After then rebuild your mainservice Docker image, push it to the registry, remove the existing image from your cluster and deploy the correct manifests. Then you should get your expected behavior.

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma ok thank you I will try.  Also just to verify, what I was thinking regarding leaving the internal code of main service pointing to localhost:8000 and redirecting that traffic somehow outside the pod to the other pod is not possible?

Comment: Ok then and let the stackoverflow community know if you have problem

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#multi-port-services

Comment: Yes, what with this doc? You can share your problem

Comment: Maybe something you are missing as per as my Kubernetes understanding. You can use multiple ports of selected Pods selected by `.spec.selector` fields. Using the port(s) that are not exposed by the selected Pods is no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main service doesn't need to know anything about the services it calls other than their names. Simply access those services using the name of the `Service`, i.e. `service1` and `service2` (http://service1:80) and the requests will be forwarded to the correct pod.

Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Comment: I understand that part, but how is written in the service, Also in my container for the main service it needs to send request to ports 8000 and 8001, if I wrote the service yaml, what does the `spec` look like can it have two parts, one for each label selector for service one and two?

Comment: The main service simply uses those names. Nothing goes to the deployment yaml, or the service yaml for the main service. If you want, you can add environment variables to the deployment yaml giving you the name and the port of service1 and service2

Comment: I added my attempt at the yaml for main service in the original post.  Please take a look.

Comment: Only add the port for the mainservice deployment. Don't add ports for the service1 and service2. The program you deploy as mainservice has to talk to `service1` and `service2` using their names. You only declare names you expose, not the names you use. `service1` and `service2` are already exposed, you simply use them in your program.

Comment: the container containing main service code doesn't know anything about the names, it only knows to send to ports 8000 and 8001, are you saying I don't need to do anything to redirect traffic from those internal ports to specific ports on the pod of main service ? If thats true then why did I have to do it for service one and two (i.e. connect container  targetPort 5000 to port 80 of pod)

Comment: Now maybe I got your problem. In your mainservice code, it makes request to `localhost:8000` for service1 and request to `localhost:8001` for service2. Right?

Comment: A k8s `Service` sends the traffic it receives to the target port in the target pod. You *have to* know which service you're calling, so you have to know the names. In your main service, you simply connect to `service1:8000` and `service2:8001`. How are you doing it now?

Comment: @erotavlas If you answer us maybe we or someone else may help you properly.

Comment: Your service1 and service2 are exposing port 80, so you actually have to connect to `service1:80` and `service2:80`

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma yes thats right main service is like asp.net core web api and in the controller it has hard coded in it to make those two requests to those two URL

Comment: @erotavlas when you deploy your app on k8s like this, those services are no longer on localhost. You have to change the main program to connect to the services by name.

Comment: @erotavlas If these all are hard coded then you need to do something different from the given solns by Arghya Shadhu and BuraSerdar. Or if you want to follow what they suggested abouve then you need to modify your mainservice code.

Comment: @erotavlas if you deploy all three services in a single pod, then you can still access those ports using localhost.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I have a feeling that is wrong, there is no way I can make a request like that from inside an ASP.NET Core application or any other language.

Comment: @erotavlas what is wrong? You cannot make a request to localhost:port, or service:port?

Comment: @BurakSerdar each service is a container and the recommendation is to keep them in separate pods.  I'm trying to learn to do it as separate pods.

Comment: @erotavlas yes, you should keep them as separate pods. Then you need to change your mainservice to use service names, not localhost. However, you *can* deploy multiple services in a single pod. Then you can access them using localhost.

Comment: @erotavlas In that case, you should rewrite your mainservice code obviously to use the kubernetes native dns name for serviceone and servicetwo Service object.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I think what I'm looking for has to do with KubeDNS (Now CoreDNS).  I think you are missing that in your answer along with what the URI should look ike in the requesting service (i.e. what should I replace localhost:80 with.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I think its something like `my-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local` - see this https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services, or are you saying you can simply use service name and omit the remaining portion `namespace.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: You can simply use the service name, and it'll resolve to the fqdn using defaults.